# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS Vino issues

Tags: 20.04, vnc, vino

So spun up a new Ubuntu 20.04 LTS vm minimal desktop installed a few apps and vino.  Configured and connected without a problem a few times.  Then needed to change the ip from dhcp to static and after a restart I was unable to connect with vnc (tried tightvnc & realvnc).

Not really sure what's happening everything seems to be working and vino is running at startup but the connection fails like its not listening or responding.

I'm not super knowledgeable so bear with me but also not seeing any issues in the logs.

Comment: Is your VM Network settings set in NAT or Bridged mode?

Comment: bridged on hyper-v

Comment: When you changed to the static IP did you make sure that you were in the same IP address range as the host OS?

Comment: Yes I'm able to access the system via putty, and a web based app installed, etc.. but not vnc/vino seems like it's not even listening.  I had previously had to change the encryption to false and it was working.  I've uninstalled & reinstalled vino and restarted the system multiple times.

Comment: You are making sure that when you launch the vnc/vino server that you are using the number that it says after the `:` to connect to, i.e. If the IP is 192.168.1.56 and the `:` number is 1 then you are connecting to 192.168.1.56:1?

Comment: hmm not sure, I was expecting it to auto start like it did originally and I was able to connect to it without specifying a parameter

Comment: When you ssh to the server run `ps -ef | grep vnc` or `ps -ef | grep vino` and look for something like this:  `terrance  141511       1  0 18:35 pts/0    00:00:00 Xtightvnc :1 -desktop` as you can see mine has a `:1` which means when I connect to it I have to put in the address as `<IP Address>:1`.  Out of curiosity though, when you spun up the minimal what Desktop did you tell it to install?  But, I really don't have a lot to go off of as you haven't specified if you are running Tight or Vino and verified that either is actually running.